# Specific .htaccess redirect based on query_string

Tags: .htaccess

I need this logic to work:

I want rewrite this string for users to see

http://mysite.com/index.php?cl=mykeystring
to
http://mysite.com/otherkey/

http://mysite.com/index.php?myvar=test&cl=mykeystring&mysecondvar=morevalue
to
http://mysite.com/otherkey/myvar=test&mysecondvar=morevalue

But when http://mysite.com/otherkey/ is written, so load 
http://mysite.com/index.php?cl=mykeystring, but no redirects will be done.

Is it possible? There are no possibility to change anything in codes, but only .htaccess

This logic is nearly realized by this code:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*?)cl=mykeystring(.*?)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^index.php$ /otherkey/%1%2? [R,L]

RewriteRule ^otherkey/(.*?)$ /index.php?cl=mykeystring&$1
```

but **im getting some not needed amp symbols on first rewrite rule. any solutions?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can do something like this:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} cl=mykeystring [NC]
RewriteRule ^index.php /otherkey/ [QSA]
```

Docs here: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html

Comment: improved my version a little, maybe you would help in the last question?